# configure vim-airline to show hostname

Tags: vim, vim-airline

Is there a way to show hostname info in the [vim airline](https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline) status bar?

I've tried adding `let g:airline_section_a = '%{hostname -s}'` to my `.vimrc` but that did not work -- I get `E121: Undefined variable: hostname`.

Edit: these two lines /almost/ work, but I get the text `calculon^@` in my statusline -- how do I get rid of the extra two characters and just display `calculon`?

```
let hostname=system('hostname -s')
let g:airline_section_a = '%{hostname}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^@` is the newline printed from `hostname -s` you could use `tr -d '\n'` to remove it:

```
let hostname=system('hostname -s | tr -d "\n"')
let g:airline_section_a = '%{hostname}'
```

You can also use the build in hostname function:

```
let g:airline_section_a = '%{hostname()}'
```

But there got to be a more elegant solution

Comment: Use vim builtin hostname() function instead: `let g:airline_section_a = '%{hostname()}'`